# Can we use single FutureTask with Executor with different purposes

Tags: android, threadpool

I used newSingleThreadExecutor with executors

```
Executor mSessionExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

here is future task which returns List

```
FutureTask<List<String>> listFutureTask = new FutureTask<List<String>>(new Callable<List<Session>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> call() throws Exception {
         return getSessions();
        }
    });
```

for getting o/p i am using below code

```
mSessionExecutor.execute(listFutureTask);
List<String> sessions= listFutureTask.get();
```

so my question is can i use same future task multiple time
as `listFutureTask.get();` returns same value always which exist while running first task

so can i use ?

```
 mSessionExecutor.execute(listFutureTask);
 mSessionExecutor.execute(listFutureTask); ..
```

multiple times so that after calling `listFutureTask.get();`  i will get updated list always

Comment: no that represents a single execution of that task.  you must re-submit to the executor each time and obtain a fresh future.

Comment: And what is written in the FutureTask's documentation?

Comment: hey men think twice before down Casting any votes.